# How to do everything that 'make install' does with 'install' for a pre-compiled package?

Tags: fedora, software-installation

I wonder what `make install` does that after successfully running this command after I just compiled a source package, my system becomes aware of the new installed package.
Let's assume I have retrieved a pre-compiled Linux package from somewhere for my distribution and want to use `install` rather than merely `cp` to install the whole unzipped package under `/usr/local` making sure that I do everything that a typical `sudo make install` does for this package. I tried running `sudo install -r -T ./[pre-compiled package] /usr/local` aiming to recursively copy everything to `/usr/local`, but it fails and seems to do nothing.

Comment: `make install` might do a lot of things, and what needs to be done depends on the software you're installing.

Answer (score 6):

`make install` executes the commands listed for the target named `install` in `./Makefile` (and the commands for any other not-yet-completed targets that install depends on - e.g. the install target usually depends on the build target(s)).  As @Henrik said, these could be anything...copying files, creating directories, setting ownership and/or permissions, creating or copying initial config files, and much more.

BTW, `make install` and the `install` command are two completely different things.  The former executes a Makefile target called "install".  The latter is kind of a fancy version of `cp` on steroids that can set owner, group, permissions, and do a bunch of other stuff that is useful when installing software - `install` is often used by install targets in Makefiles.

Anyway, `make` and `make install` are pretty much irrelevant to what you want to do - install pre-compiled software.

To install pre-compiled software, if you have a package for your distro (e.g. a `.rpm` or `.deb` file), then use the distro packaging tools to install it - e.g. `dpkg` on debian/ubuntu, `rpm` for fedora etc.  If you don't have a copy of the package yet, but it **is** available as a package for your distro then use `apt` (debian) or `dnf` or `yum` (fedora) to fetch and install it.

For pre-compiled software that isn't a proper distro package (e.g. a tar.gz containing a bunch of files), and you can't find source code or a package for it, your best option is to use a program like [GNU Stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) or similar.

`stow` makes it fairly easy to install unpackaged software and still be able to uninstall it later (e.g. to prepare for upgrading to a new version) without leaving a huge mess of orphaned files behind....which is exactly what a simple untar or cp **will** do.

Unmanaged software is a mess waiting to happen.  Use the package tools provided by your system if at all possible.  if not, use something like `stow`.

---

One other program I intended to mention when I wrote this yesterday was [checkinstall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CheckInstall), but I just couldn't remember its name until now.  `checkinstall` makes it easy to make a functional, if less than perfect, package of any software that you would otherwise install with `make install`.  It's not much use for binary-only pre-compiled programs (e.g. proprietary software) but can be very useful when the source is available.

Comment: Tthere are several [questions tagged `/stow`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stow) here with useful and informative answers.